# Log org.springframework

Tags: spring-security, log4j

I have a non-Spring appliation.   However, we are pulling in spring-security-config and spring-security-web.   We use Log4j and have a log4j.properties file.

We want to log all the output from 'org.springframework' with the 'trace' log level.

We do not have an application.properties file, but can create one if we need one.

So, when I run my non-Spring app, all my code logs properyly, but I am not seeing anything from org.springframework in my logs.

Since Spring Security pulls in Spring Core, we created an application.properties on the classpath.  We then setup a logging.file property to our log file.  Then we setup some other logging property files to see if that would help.  We also set debug=true as well.

So, I'll keep trying ....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the problem.   The logs were going to another log file in a different directory.   I believe this is because it was a container log and not an application log.

Hope this helps someone else out.